# Visual Studio 2015 $(VC_LibraryPath_x64) pointing at non-existent directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015, my $(VC_LibraryPath_x64) is pointing at xxx\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\xxx for folders which don't exist (Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 does exist though).

The correct folders it should be pointing at (which contains lib files the compiler complains are missing) is xxx\Microsfot Visual Studio 14.0\xxx

I'm not sure why it's pointing at the wrong dirs, any ideas how I can fix the directory macros?

Comment: Happens when you open a project that was created to work on an older version of VS but you don't have that version installed.  And, usually, it wasn't property uninstalled so you don't get a decent error message, a very common issue with programmers that kick the tires on beta and trial versions.  Project > Properties > General > Platform Toolset setting, needs to be v140.  Fixing the registry damage, well, not so easy.  Either just keep in mind that it is going to happen again or consider a good lazy day to wipe the machine.

Comment: yep that changed the directories, will probs do a reformat if I get the chance, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Open the project properties and update the Platform Toolset as Visual studio 2015(v140). Apply the settings. 
Now check again. The macro VC_LibraryPath_x64 should now point to 14.0 directories.